# Why jest fails with "component is part of the declaration of 2 modules"?

Tags: angular, jestjs, nrwl-nx

I'm getting the following exception within executing a test in an angular (nx) project:

```
Error: Type FooComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: FooComponentModule and FooComponentModule! Please consider moving FooComponent to a higher module that imports FooComponentModule and FooComponentModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FooComponent then import that NgModule in FooComponentModule and FooComponentModule.
```

The thing is I'm getting this exception only in IntelliJ (2022.3.1, MacOS) when I use the build-in jest integration. A colleague with Windows is getting this exception everywhere.

I was trying to execute the test [app.component.spec.ts](https://github.com/iceteabottle/nx-test-project/blob/main/apps/my-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts) in my [test project](https://github.com/iceteabottle/nx-test-project). The test should be executed successfully – everywhere not only in the CLI.
The craziest thing is: I copied the command IntelliJ is executing within the build-in jest integration to the build-in terminal and it just works

I'm really unsure where to address this issue. Is this an issue with jest? Angular? NX? IntelliJ?

**Update:**

It seems to be an nx related issue. I created a simple clean angular project with jest and the same prerequisites (like lib, path aliases) and everything worked as expected.

**Update 2:**

I created an issue in the nx repo: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/14494

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of configuration in the test runner that you are not using when you run the command directly in the terminal. Could be?

Comment: @JuanAntonio when you look at this issue only from my side. Yes, it could be the problem theoretically. But that would not explain why my colleague with a Windows machine get that exception everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for the issue.

```js
// jest.preset.js
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset').default;

module.exports = {
  ...nxPreset,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@nx-test-project/my-lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../../libs/my-lib/src/$1',
  }
};
```

See https://github.com/iceteabottle/nx-test-project/commit/b376c06f78cd14a5304b71908b2dfe4e8e854ed0

The issue is caused by webpack's path aliases. Jest itself doesn't understand these aliases obviously. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/299576

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the solution of the main problem but to use [standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components) instead of SCAM Components would help and avoid the exception.